# Error al conectar una API entre Heroku y Firebase

Tags: firebase, api, heroku, cors

Buen día,
Tengo un error al conectar mi API.
Subí un frontend desarrollado en Angular a Firebase, y un backend desarrollado en Java con Spring Boot a Heroku y una base de datos MySql a Clever Cloud pero por algún motivo no conectan. La solicitud de conexión devuelve un error status 503. Comparto capturas del error, el codigo y en el registro de logs de Heroku.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el application.properties desde donde hago la conexión a la base de datos:

```
En application.properties tengo este codigo:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://umunsm56uas95xk4:yABcXpJ62MelJfjujs7Q@b1lqceu1biznxgydh0r4-
spring.datasource.username=xxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxx
spring.jpa.show.sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Tengo configurado un archivo system.properties en java con este codigo:

```
java.runtime.version=17
maven.version=3.6.2
```

Este es el registro completo de logs de la consola de Heroku CLI:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CdIDCGhZONPqbMKEjDhhVXuP0-iYhj52-_mZ3c-wLe8/edit?usp=sharing

Estos son los logs del panel de heroku:

```
2022-05-01T20:35:31.276331+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
2022-05-01T20:35:31.276332+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
2022-05-01T20:35:31.276332+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar!/:5.3.15]
2022-05-01T20:35:31.276332+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 44 common frames omitted
2022-05-01T20:35:31.276333+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-05-01T20:35:31.435879+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-01T20:35:31.502597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-01T20:35:54.636572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=portfolioargentinaprograma.herokuapp.com request_id=65cf3552-8357-4448-b57a-972aef88fb13 fwd="186.141.199.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-01T20:35:55.027091+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=portfolioargentinaprograma.herokuapp.com request_id=e1f234fc-6304-42f9-9a30-c0c8d94a024c fwd="186.141.199.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-01T20:35:56.254494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=portfolioargentinaprograma.herokuapp.com request_id=2eaed1b2-cbee-45fc-a750-5dadd83a001b fwd="186.141.199.124" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Alguna idea de donde puede estar el error?

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo pasar por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) y leer el artículo [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder editar tu pregunta y agregar tanto detalles como código.

Comment: Lo que está fallando es tu api. No es posible ver los logs que adjuntas porque no tienes acceso público. ¿Comprobaste la api desactivando temporalmente el cors y usando postman?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Lo siento, ya actualice el link para que sea de acceso publico. Lo dejo acá también si te resulta mas cómodo: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bD7MDO-_ZttuX4LVz96XPdXsgs7YzvjYvEpucllcfmY/edit?usp=sharing  Deshabilite los CORS con CrossOrigin he hice las pruebas con postman pero todos los llamado me siguen devolviendo el mismo error un status 503.

Comment: Ah pos está clarísimo `java.net.UnknownHostException`. Basicamente no se puede conectar a la base de datos. No puede resolver el host ¿Estás seguro puedes acceder a la DB desde heroku? ¿Dónde tienes la db?

Comment: Es verdad que ese era uno de los errores, había un error de tipeo en la conexión a la base de datos. Ya lo corregí pero sigo sin poder conectarme. Un error muy similar. Las base de datos la tengo en Clever Cloud

Comment: Bueno, actualiza los logs y muestralos sin ese error. ¿Tienes el driver para mysql en tu classpath?

Comment: Si, tengo el driver. Este es el nuevo registro de logs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DCklBmtTUZLMp0joxOAtLKb_8HZtxcT0ploGU7eLfh8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Además encontré dos errores en el registro de logs de heroku que me devuelve cuando hago el deploy: --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:list (default-cli) @ Web ---
       [INFO] Can't extract module name from h2-2.1.210.pom.sha512: Module format not recognized: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/2.1.210/h2-2.1.210.pom.sha512
       [INFO] Can't extract module name from spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.6.3.pom: Module format not recognized: /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.6.3/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.6.3.pom

Comment: ¿Podrías probar eliminando de tus properties la línea `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect `?

Comment: Hice el deploy con los cambios que me sugeriste pero continua el problema. Note que en el pom tengo en las dos dependencias que no reconoce el formato una etiqueta que no esta en el resto del pom que es <type>pom.sha512</type> y <type>pom</type>. Podrá ser que esta etiqueta este generando el problema? Si se la saco tendré problemas con el funcionamiento después?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y adjunta el pom.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta y agregue el pom. En las dependencias de h2 y de spring-boot-starter-data-jpa esta esta etiqueta <type>

Comment: Ahora quita de la dependencia de `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` el `<type>pom</type>` y de `h2` quita el `<type>pom.sha512</type>`. Guarda los cambios y ve a ver si al menos los warnings se eliminan

Comment: Esos dos warnings se eliminaron, pero sigue sin funcionar. Voy a editar la pregunta con el registro de logs del panel de heroku. Da algunos errores pero no se a que se refieren. Lo agrego en la pregunta.

Comment: Quita todo lo demás irrelevante a tu pregunta. Edítala y céntrala en lo que es el error como tal: Tu api en springboot. La eliminación de los warnings ya es un avance.

Comment: Los logs de heroku se ven incompletos. ¿Puedes adjuntar todos?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta y remplace el archivo donde estaba el registro de logs completo de la consola de heroku cli. Cambio bastante el resultado de los registros.

Comment: Ya esta, logre hacer que funcione!!! Le quite esta linea: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver2 del application.properties. Creo que hubiese funcionado igual con esa linea pero sin el 2 del final. Además volví a agregar esta linea: spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect. Que había olvidado poner después de quitarla. Mil gracias por su tiempo!!!

Comment: ¿Y en que momento tenías esa línea con el 2? En lo que pones en tu pregunta no se ve nada :V. De cualquier manera, me alegra se arreglara, pero por favor, que esta experiencia te sirva para aprender a preguntar. Tienes que adjuntar exactamente lo que obtienes, y acotar el error todo lo posible. Buena suerte con tu app!

Comment: Si, es verdad que no estaba. Se ve que en alguna de las ediciones lo agregue sin darme cuenta. Mala mía! Pero por suerte se resolvió!!